# How to Display images in vuetify datatable using paths

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I have this array item :

```
[
  {
    "name": "user language check dates in different language",
    "tag": "@DHRD-52484",
    "status": "passed",
    "refimages": [
      "/captures/ref_01_03_2022_17_05_21/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/1.png",
      "/captures/ref_01_03_2022_17_05_21/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/2.png",
      "/captures/ref_01_03_2022_17_05_21/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/3.png",
      "/captures/ref_01_03_2022_17_05_21/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/4.png"
    ],
    "testimages": [
      "/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/1.png",
      "/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/2.png",
      "/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/3.png",
      "/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/4.png"
    ],
    "resultimages": [
      "/VisualTests/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/1.png",
      "/VisualTests/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/2.png",
      "/VisualTests/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/3.png",
      "/VisualTests/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/4.png"
    ]
  }
]
```

and I've been trying to have a table using vuetify with each row representing the index of the image,the refimage, testimage and result image
this is my code so far :

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-navbar />

    <v-main>
      <h3>
        test {{ $route.params.name }}, {{ $route.query.status }},{{
          $route.query.tag
        }}
      </h3>
      <h3>{{ imagesref }}</h3>
      <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import appNavbar from "../../../components/appNavbar.vue"
import axios from "axios"
export default {
  components: { appNavbar },
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      imagesref: [],
      imagestest: [],
      imagesresult: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: "index",
          align: "start",
          sortable: false,
          value: "index",
        },
        { text: "reference image", value: "refimages" },
        { text: "test image", value: "test" },
        { text: "result image", value: "result" },
      ],
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/tests`, {
        params: { name: this.$route.params.name },
      })
      this.items = res.data
      this.imagesref = res.data[0].refimages
      this.imagestest = res.data[0].testimages
      this.imagesresult = res.data[0].resultimages
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

I tried saving the refimages,testimages and resultimages array in 3 variables but I still don't know how can i iterate over these 3 arrays in parallel and use the img tag to display the image from the path

Comment: `v-for` may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for your problem that for better explaining that, I separate it to some **steps**:

> ### step1: Test the img urls

First of all put an `<img>` tag to the component to test that the urls you defined in your data actually works or not:

```
<img width="50" src="../assets/images/1.png">
```

Here I have `1.png` image in my `assets` directory. If that does not show the image, that means your url address (for example `/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/1.png`) have some problem. Try to fix that to continue.

> ### step2: Store data in "json" file

After that if you do not have any problems with your images `urls`, you must paste your data in a json file that is saved in your `public` directory. Here I called it `dataMe.json` and put these sample data on it. you can put your own data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "tag": "@DHRD-52484-1",
    "status": "passed",
    "imgUrl": "1.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "tag": "@DHRD-52484-2",
    "status": "passed",
    "imgUrl": "2.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "tag": "@DHRD-52484-3",
    "status": "passed",
    "imgUrl": "5.png"
  }
]
```

At this point, if you paste `http://localhost:8080/dataMe.json` (instead of **8080**, use your own port number) in your browser address bar, you should see the data that is in the file in your browser.

> ### step3: Change your `template` and `script` codes

If you want to iterate over your data in **vuetify** table, you should **not** separate the data. All the data comes from your **axios** request must be in `items` data of your vue component. Here is the code of my component:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    
    <v-main>
      <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
      >
        <!-- This template is used to have custom html elements in your specific column of the table -->
        <template v-slot:item.imgUrl="{ item }">
          <!-- You can uncomment the line below to see the actual item data. Also you can use 'v-for' or 'v-if' or other vue capabilities, if your item data is more complex.  -->
          
<!--          <span>{{item}}</span>-->
          <img width="50" :src="require(`../assets/images/${item.imgUrl}`)">
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios"
export default {
  name: "DataView",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      // imagesref: [],
      // imagestest: [],
      // imagesresult: [],
      headers: [
        { text: "name", value: "name" },
        { text: "tag", value: "tag" },
        { text: "status", value: "status" },
        { text: "image", value: "imgUrl" },
      ],
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      // replace the port number with your own port number
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMe.json');
      console.log(res.data);
      this.items = res.data;
      // this.imagesref = res.data[0].refimages
      // this.imagestest = res.data[0].testimages
      // this.imagesresult = res.data[0].resultimages
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

As you can see I used `v-data-table` [Slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots) capability to handle the image problem. With this capability of **vuetify** you can add or replace custom html elements to built-in vuetify components. Also see [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item) to better understand the usage of **Slots** in `v-data-table` component.

The last tip that I think is necessary to mention is that **do not** put the whole address of your images in the json data file. Put only the **variable** part (for example `1.png` and `2.png` and so on) and for the repeated part (for example `/captures/test_07_03_2022_10_13_48/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language`) put that in `:src="require(...` part of your vue template code.

That is the solution that works with my sample data. You may need to add more columns or change your `headers` or `items` part of your table to have the desired table that you want with your own data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hamid-davodi for your solution! I have also tried finding my own and here's what I came up with:

```
    <template>
      <v-app>
               
        <app-navbar />
    
        <v-main>
     
          <h3>
            test {{ $route.params.name }}, {{ $route.query.status }},{{
              $route.query.tag
            }}
          </h3>
          <h3>{{ imagesref }}</h3>
      
            <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="imagesref"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
      <template v-slot:[`item.index`]="{ index }">
         
            {{index+1}}
      </template>
      
      <template v-slot:[`item.ref`]="{ index }">
    
            <v-img :src="imagesref[index]" max-width="750" max-height="750" @click="expand"  />
      
      </template>
       <template v-slot:[`item.test`]="{ index }">
         
            <v-img :src="imagestest[index]" max-width="750" max-height="750" />
    
      </template>
         <template v-slot:[`item.res`]="{ index }">
         
            <v-img :src="imagesresult[index]" max-width="750" max-height="750" />
    
      </template>
      </v-data-table>
    
    
        </v-main>
     
      </v-app>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import appNavbar from "../../../components/appNavbar.vue"
    import axios from "axios"
    export default {
      components: { appNavbar },
      name: "App",
      data() {
        return {
          exp:false,
          items: [],
          imagesref: [],
          imagestest: [],
          imagesresult: [],
                  headers: [
              { text: 'index',value: 'index',sortable:false},
              { text: 'Imagesref', value: 'ref',sortable:false },
              { text: 'Imagestest', value: 'test',sortable:false },
              { text: 'Imagesresult', value: 'res',sortable:false },
              { text: 'Scrubber', value: '',sortable:false },
            ]
        }
      },
      async created() {
        try {
          const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/tests`, {
            params: { name: this.$route.params.name },
          })
          this.items = res.data
          this.imagesref = res.data[0].refimages
          this.imagestest = res.data[0].testimages
          this.imagesresult = res.data[0].resultimages
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      },
      methods:{
        expand(){
          this.exp= !this.exp;
    
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style  scoped>

    </style>
```

Since the paths of the images are ordered in the array, I used v-slot with the index object to display each image in the correct row.
I'm using nuxtjs, so I saved the images in the static folder so that I wouldn't need to change the path.

I hope this can help a fellow beginner in vue/vuetify.